# Apache CXF - Handle missing path parameters in an operation

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs

I am using apache cxf for Jax-rs implementation in my project. I have a service defined with the following address:
http://ip:port/myservice/{operation}

consider an operation for this server defined as below

```
@Override
@GET
@Path("operation1/{x}/{y}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String operation1(@PathParam("x") final String x, @PathParam("y") final String y) {
    return null;
}
```

In the scenario where the requester makes a request with some operation name that is not defined in myservice, it will return 404 which is expected behavior. But i am getting the same 404 in cases where operation name is correctly requested but path parameters are not. I would like to create a proper error if any of {x} or {y} path param is missing in a request. But i cannot find a graceful way where i can handle exceptions as per the operations. CXF never maps to the operation in such cases.

I have this exception mapper:

```
public class ClientExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ClientErrorException> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(final ClientErrorException exception) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity("Invalid request").build();

}
```

}

Which will handle all error cases but it doesn't provide any information as to what URL was requested in the exception.
Is there a way where i can handle exceptions differently for different operations in cases when path parameters are not defined ?
For eg: I would like to handle following request with some custom logic defined for operation1 only.
http://ip:port/myservice/operation1/20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two solutions for your case.
1) Move your path params to query param. `@QueryParam`
2) Create a filter and map it to url `operation1/*`

Comment: And how exactly can i put a filter on a specific URL pattern in CXF ??

Comment: You can check articles for example this https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/java-ee-7/9781449370589/ch04.html or this http://www.developerscrappad.com/1781/java/java-ee/rest-jax-rs/java-ee-7-jax-rs-2-0-cors-on-rest-how-to-make-rest-apis-accessible-from-a-different-domain/

Comment: I looked into the interceptors and found them overly complicated. I didn't have time to understand the whole interceptor mechanism in CXF (which you must) for my one situation, but still i think that will be a better approach to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

While finding solution for my scenario where i need to validate path parameters, i found [this link](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/15/jax-rs-path-pathparam-and-optional-parameters/) which suggests a nice workaround for my problem. Although its just a hack and might not be a good idea to implement in existing code, you can consider it if you need to play around with path parameters within your respective operation.